# Need burst speed messages per second for devices at various times during a day with Azure IoT hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub

While Azure Event hub can have thousands and million? of messages per second, the Azure IoT hub has a surprisingly low limitation on this.

- S1 has 12 msg/sec speed but allow 400.000 daily msg pr. unit
- S2 has 120 msg/sec speed but allow 6.000.000 daily msg pr. unit
- S3 has 6000 msg/sec speed but allow 300.000.000 daily msg pr unit.

Imagine an IoT solution where your devices normally sends 1 message every hour, but have the ability to activate a short "realtime" mode to send messages every second for about 2 minutes duration.

**Example: 10.000 IoT devices:**

Let's say 20% of these devices happens to start a realtime mode session simultaneously 4 times a day. (We do not have control over when those are started by individual customers). That is 2000 devices and burst speed needed is then 2000 msg/second.

**Daily msg need:**

- Normal messages: 10.000dev * 24hours = 240.000 msg/day
- Realtime messages daily count: 2.000dev * 120msg(2 min with 1 msg every second) * 4times a day = 960.000 messages
  Total daily msg count need: 240.000 + 960000 msg = 1.200.000 msg/day.
  Needed Azure IoT hub tier: S1 with 3 units gives 1.200.000 msg/day. **($25 * 3units = $75/month)**

**Burst speed needed:**

- 2000 devices sending simultaneously every second for a couple of
  minutes a few times a day: 2000 msg/second. Needed Azure IoT hub
  tier: S2 with 17 units gives speed 2040 msg/second. ($250 * 17units =
  $4250/month) Or go for S3 with 1 unit, which gives speed 6000
  msg/second. **($2500/month)**

The daily message count requires only a low IoT hub tier due to the modest messages per day count, but the need for burst speed when realtime is activated requires an unproportionally very high IoT hub tier which skyrockets(33 times) the monthly costs for the solution, ruining the businesscase.

**Is it possible to allow for temporary burst speeds at varying times during a day as long as the total number of daily messages sent does not surpass current tier max limit?**

I understood from an article from 2016 by Nicole Berdy that the throttling on Azure IoT hub is in place to avoid DDOS attacks and misuse. However to be able to simulate realtime mode functionality with Azure IoT hub we need more Event Hub like messages/second speed. Can this be opened up by contacting support or something? Will it help if the whole solution is living inside its own protected network bubble?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **real-time needs** definitely, always consider [Azure IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/about-iot-edge?view=iotedge-2018-06) and double check if it is possible to implement it on your scenario.

In the calculations you did above you refer, for example that S2 has 120 **msg**/sec speed. That is not fully correct. Let me explain better:

- The throttle for Device-to-cloud **sends** is applied only if you overpass 120 **send operations**/sec/unit
- Each message can be up to 256 KB which is the maximum message size.

Therefore, the questions you need to answer to successfully implement your scenario with the lowest cost possible are:

1. What is the message size of my devices?
2. Do I need to display messages in near-real-time on customer's Cloud Environment, or my concern is the **level of detail** of the sensors during a specific time?
3. When I enable "burst mode" am I leveraging the [batch mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-sdk-c-iothubclient#configuration-options) of Azure IoT SDK?

To your questions:

> Is it possible to allow for temporary burst speeds at varying times
> during a day as long as the total number of daily messages sent does
> not surpass current tier max limit?

No, the limits for example to S2 are 120 device-to-cloud send operations/sec/unit.

> Can this be opened up by contacting support or something? Will it help
> if the whole solution is living inside its own protected network
> bubble?

No, the only exception is when you need to increase the total number of devices plus modules that can be registered to a single IoT Hub for more than 1,000,000. On that case you shall contact Microsoft Support.

Comment: Thank you for answering, asergaz!

As every single sensor is on a different network (its own customer) I guess edge is not feasible in this setup.

Also every message is needed as fast as it is available(every second). We cannot wait to batch up some messages because that wait-time would ruin the realtime-experience. 

Think Tesla car app where you get realtime update of the car driving on the map. No delay. The update seems realtime as the car drives.

It would be nice if the IoT hub offered 2 scaling option sliders. One for messages/sec and one for msg/day. Easier to balance cost.

Comment: This is a great idea @Frode . Can I suggest you add the idea here and upvote it? https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot-hub-dps-sdks

Comment: Done. Good suggestion!

Comment: Adding UserVoice thread for others to vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot-hub-dps-sdks/suggestions/43219920-allow-option-for-both-scaling-msg-day-and-scaling